# Process a RACSequence or RACSignal in batches

Tags: ios, objective-c, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

**Update 3/5/14:** RACSequence is deprecated in ReactiveCocoa 3.0 (see comments), but I'm still curious about the best way to process data in batches, either using RACSequence or RACSignal.

I'm trying to process a potentially large array of values using ReactiveCocoa. My idea is to split the input sequence into smaller sequences up to a maximum size, and then process them separately (potentially in parallel).

I've written a category method on RACSequence to do the chunking:

```
// Returns a sequence of sequences of at most `size` objects

- (RACSequence *)chunk:(NSInteger)size
{
    if ([self head] == nil) {
        return [RACSequence empty];
    }

    RACSequence *chunk = [self take:size];
    RACSequence *rest  = [self skip:size];

    return [RACSequence sequenceWithHeadBlock:^id {
        return chunk;
    } tailBlock:^RACSequence *{
        return [rest chunk:size];
    }];
}
```

This works, but it's extremely slow for large sequences. [I wrote an iterative version and a utility to compare the two approaches](https://gist.github.com/cspickert/9348928). Here's the difference for a sequence of 10000 numbers broken into smaller sequences of up to 30 objects:

```
$ time ./main i 10000 30 # Iterative
2014-03-04 10:48:28.845 main[59637:507] Number of chunks: 334

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.007s
sys 0m0.004s

$ time ./main r 10000 30 # Recursive
2014-03-04 10:48:45.423 main[59645:507] Number of chunks: 334

real    0m15.513s
user    0m15.133s
sys 0m0.378s
```

Is there a better way to process a RACSequence in smaller batches?

Comment: You probably already knew this, but JFYI RACSequence gets deprecated in ReactiveCocoa 3: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/890